# Deny all files except the index using apache

Tags: php, .htaccess, indexing

Here's my *.htaccess*

```
<Files *>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
</Files>

<Files index.php>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from all
</Files>
```

This is not working, cause if I type the hostname in my browser, it serves the index.php but apache doesn't seem to apply the Files instructions and instead returns a non-allowed file access page, I need typing the fullname document (e.g. 'index.php') to make it work. which is not really convenient...

how to proceed if I want users only access index files of each folder in my website ?
all the other files are just script inclusions so i believe i'm doing right trying to make them inaccessible from the web (or maybe not, if only you have one reason to prove the other case).

Regardless the question above, is it the right way to do the job ? (I think the two  directives here are not neat but it's the only way, well almost the only way that I know to avoid accesses to files).

Comment: You know, why bother with that, when all u have to do is just remove all your files outside the htdocs/www folder, except the index.php ?

Comment: If you don't want something accessible, then don't put it into the webroot. Far easier to move them elsewhere than try to coerce Apache into serving up only SOME files.

Comment: @MarcB so If I hear you guys, my webroot is going to be only one .htaccess file using mod_rewrite to load outter content ? this is not really easy task for web development.

Comment: You'd still have your index.php. But if you don't want those other "include" type files available, then don't have them in the webroot.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure why you need to do this, but you can use `mod_setenvif` (no need to wrap this inside a `<Files>`)

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/index.php$ index
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from env=index
```

This will cause access to hostname.com/ to 403 but allow hostname.com/index.php. If you want to allow / as well, just add

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/$ index
```

to the top. Of course, all this will make it so anything that index.php links to will also return a 403.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Files *?>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

You just need to add a question mark to match at least one character.