# Apache deny requests from IP ranges, except for errordocs

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have an .htacces as below to block all requests from a number of IP subnets.

```
<Files ~ "^.*$">
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Deny from ipa.ddr.ess.sub/net
        Deny from ipa.ddr.ess.sub/net
        ...
</Files>
```

The problem is that my error log shows two errors for each bad IP address:

```
... client denied by server configuration: .../public_html/node
... client denied by server configuration: .../public_html/403.shtml
```

How can I change the Files block in such a way that it rejects all requests from these IP-addresses, except for the error documents (403.shtml)?

Checked several question, but they don't seem to work with the extra deny from ip addresses. Eg. [Deny all files except the index using apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956385/deny-all-files-except-the-index-using-apache)

Comment: At least take the effort of explaining why this question should be closed. Lots of .htaccess questions are on SO.SE.

Comment: I think the `shtml` might be the problem. Try changing it to just `html`

Comment: @Gerben I took it a step further as I would have to change the ErrorDocument to ...html anyway. I put a `ErrorDocument 403 "<h1>Forbidden</h1>"` into the .htaccess. Unfortunately I can only check logs tomorrow, but it seems to work just fine for now.

Comment: @Gerben my ErrorDocument trick worked.

Comment: It has been 3 years, how is this question not answered. This is the result I find when I Google "how to deny requests to all documents except one", and I still don't have my answer.